# How can I Select N most recent rows with unique column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to perform a query for retrieving the N (in this case 4) most recent rows from a table which all have different values on a specific column.

the table is an impressions table from which I need to retrieve the 4 unique most recent pages the user has visited, identified by a page_id colun. My main issue arises in the case the user has visited the same page consecutively, so if I perform a naive

```
SELECT page_id 
FROM impressions 
WHERE user_id = #### 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 4;
```

I end up with repeated values.

I stumbled upon an answer here which I can't seem to find again which suggested using window functions to which I tried

```
SELECT page_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY page_id) as rnk
FROM impressions
WHERE user_id = ####
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Which yields more or less what I want, getting the following results:

```
   page_id | rnk 
-----------+-----
       325 |  10
       325 |  10
       524 |  20
       235 |   5
       235 |   5
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       524 |  20
       499 |  13
       499 |  13
```

The question is how from here, maybe using this query as a starting point I can end up with something like

```
   page_id | rnk 
-----------+-----
       325 |  10
       524 |  20
       235 |   5
       499 |  13
```

Comment: You may find `DISTINCT`, `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT` useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by`:

```
SELECT page_id 
FROM impressions 
WHERE user_id = #### 
GROUP BY page_id
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC
LIMIT 4;
```